# How to Upload .aspx websites onto APACHE Tomcat

Tags: asp.net, tomcat, aspxgridview

I have created a website that has an extension of .aspx using Microsoft Expression Web 4 and I need to upload it onto out APACHE TOMCAT server. Is there anyone that can guide me how to do this?

Comment: sorry but that's not possible....razor needs .net to compile

Answer (score 0):

I host my websites only on Windows web hosting.  Click on the link below and then click on the link about Mono-Project to see if that could help you.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/167026/how-to-deploy-Asp-Net-app-on-tomcat-apache.aspx

Comment: I also tried hosting it through IIS server. The issue I face with that is, I do not know why computers outside my network are not able to access my website. Would you know why?